# I need to divide the browser router in two

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working in a project where i need to divide the browser router in two, one for the public users and other for the admins, this is my idea:

```html
<BrowserRouter>
  <Layout>
    <Route exact path="/" component="{Home}">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/cart" component="{Cart}" />
        <Route exact path="/product/:productId" component="{ProductPage}" />
        <Route component="{NotFound}" />
      </Switch>
    </Route>
  </Layout>

  <AdminLayout>
    <Route exact path="/admin" component="{AdminHome}">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/products" component="{AdminProductsList}" />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/product/:productId"
          component="{AdminEditProduct}"
        />
        <Route component="{NotFound}" />
      </Switch>
    </Route>
  </AdminLayout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

it clearly doesn't work this way but i would like to know which is the best way to make this work

**UPDATE**

now i've been working on it and i got to this

```html
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Layout>
      <Route path="/">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component="{Home}" />
          <Route exact path="/cart" component="{Cart}" />
          <Route exact path="/product/:productId" component="{ProductPage}" />
          <Route component="{NotFound}" />
        </Switch>
      </Route>
    </Layout>

    <AdminLayout>
      <Route path="/admin">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component="{AdminHome}" />
          <Route exact path="/products" component="{AdminProductsList}" />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/product/:productId"
            component="{AdminEditProduct}"
          />
          <Route component="{NotFound}" />
        </Switch>
      </Route>
    </AdminLayout>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

the public("/") route works just fine but the admin("/admin") throws me a 404

Answer (score 0):

you can have two array objects for two rules (`admin` and `user`), and then you can map it to `Route` components , like:

```
adminRoutes = [{path: '/admin', component: AdminHome, ...}]
nomralUserRoutes = [{path: '/', component: UserHome, isExact: true, ...}]
routes = isAdmin ? adminRoutes : nomralUserRoutes
render(){
  return (
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
  routes.map(route => (<Route exact path={route.path} component={route.component} ... />))
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>)
}
```

Its just an example and you can make the route objects more complex to support more functionalities like `Auth` and ...

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I solve this problem is with a PrivateRoute HOC. You can modify this to your authentication needs.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
  />
);
PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Then use this HOC wherever you want a route that is protected.

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/products" component={AdminProductsList} />
<PrivateRoute exact path="/product/:productId" component={AdminEditProduct} />
```

Comment: can you explain a little more about PrivateRoute HOC?

Comment: Sure so it can take the place of <Route> because it will call the React-Router <Route> internally. It will check the Redux store state of in my face auth.isAuthenticated which is a boolean set by the login methods. It will then either render the child component you set when you called <PrivateRoute ...args component={MySecretComponent} if that boolean is set to true otherwise it pass in the Redirect from react-router-dom that will push the client to the designated route, in my case /login.

Comment: is a cool feature to use in the future but not what i'm searching now, for now i just want to have switch with 2 routes so if i go to "/admin" i have something and if i go to "/" and then both of this routes must have another switch inside for the other components, of course that i could simply just write "/admin/products", "/admin/product/:productId", but is not very scalable, i just did some of the code work, i will update the post, but still doesn't work 100%